# How to intercept access a web from google and Convert to a localhost

Tags: python, html

as question ，I am a novice programmer. I want to block a page from a Google search and redirect it to a localhost page .  how to do this without using a browser plugin.

Comment: that really depends on the level of access of the system in question. And the type of system. And what exactly you want to intercept. Easiest would be using the [hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Answer (score 0):

windows edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and linux `/etc/hosts`, add the following lines

```
127.0.0.1 google.com
127.0.0.1 www.google.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried, but it didn't work very well. Maybe there's something wrong with what I described. What I need to implement is , first intercept a domain name, then bypass HTTP authentication information and access my localhost directly.Looking forward to your next comments .